# How to change keyboard layout from US to NO in Ubuntu 17?

Tags: keyboard, 17.04

I have installed Ubuntu 17 as a virtual machine in Windows 10, VMware player. Windows 10 is using Norwegian keyboard layout. When I log on to Ubuntu it used American keyboard layout.

How can I change it to Norwegian?

I dont want to change the language, only keyboard.

Comment: Look at keyboard settings?

Comment: Try **Settings > Region & Language > Input Sources**.